How can I ensure the right-side content stays proportionate o
Problem Description
I'm building a responsive authentication page in Flutter that works in landscape mode without scrolling. The left section displays an image, while the right section contains forms and buttons. The challenge is ensuring responsiveness, especially for the right-side content, without enabling scrolling.
class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
      DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);

    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: Row(
        children: [
          // Left-side image
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: CardsImage(screenHeight: screenHeight),
          ),
          // Right-side form
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: screenWidth * 0.03,
                vertical: screenHeight * 0.02,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  // Repeated BlocBuilder handling AuthState logic
                  // Form fields and buttons
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

What I've Tried

Used Flexible for both sections.

Calculated padding and margins as percentages of the screen dimensions.

Tried using ScreenUtil for responsive scaling, but the issue persists.



You can try Expanded, or GridView.builder use like this
GridView.builder(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          primary: true,
                          shrinkWrap: false,
                          gridDelegate:
                          const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 1),
                        )

